# can't generate/display signed float values using python/gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal, mapwindow

I'm trying to create a raster with signed float values as the pixel values and display the results in MapWindow on windows.

What is the proper gdal band type to use?  I've tried both **gdal.GDT_Byte** and **gdal.GDT_Float32** and using both methods I can't seem to get the pixels displayed.  If I change the pixel value to the abs() value they will display.

```
dataset = driver.Create(filename, cols, rows, number_of_bands, gdal.GDT_Byte)
```

**gdal.GDT_CFloat32** allows for negative numbers but doesn't properly display the floating point value past the point.

Comment: There's something strange about this question, because there is no such thing as an *unsigned* float, afaik.  I wonder what kind of values you really are trying to store in this raster?

Comment: I too want to store DEM data as plain headerless binary float32. I'm using a workaround, but I'm surprised GDAL can't handle plain old binary format.

Comment: Please describe this workaround, so others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

gdal.GDT_Byte is 8 bit unsigned (0-255). You don't want that.  You want gdal.GDT_Float32. If you can't see the result, try calculating statistics - `dataset.ComputeStatistics(0)` - before displaying.